# 1d convolution for vector

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm learning to understand how to use the convolutional neural network with 1d convolution:

Here is a homework example:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D


epochs=20
batch_size=50
num_classes=20


x_train = np.random.rand(60000,400)
x_val = np.random.rand(10000,400)

y_tain = np.eye(20)[np.random.choice(5, 60000)]
y_val = np.eye(20)[np.random.choice(5, 10000)]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(400,)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train, y_tain,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
score = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

When I tried to run it, I got some errors:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

How do you make it compile
?

Comment: third (actually, first) dimension is for the batch size.

Comment: How do you make it compile??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look closely at the error message: your input is two-dimensional and your convolution layer expects three dimensions...

Comment: This is true, but how do you get it fixed? i.e. how do you run 1d convolutions in vector data (which are 1d -> 2d tensors including bathes)?