# 1D convolution on flat, one-dimensional data (i.e. no timeseries)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training in a dataset in which (some of) the neighboring features exhibit very strong correlations. In order to help the neural network, I am thinking of adding some 1D convolutions as the first layers. Even though 1D convolutions are mostly used to time series/nlp data, I see no theoretical reason why they cannot be used vector-wise in any type of data.

But I am not able to make `keras.layers.Conv1D` work, since its apparently designed for time-series data. A MRV example is the following:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Input(10,),
            keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', name="conv_1"),
            keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
        ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> > ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 10]

In that, I believe the "*found ndim=2*" corresponds to a tensor of `[batch_size, 10]` while it expects a tensor of shape `[series_length, batch_size, 10]` (or some other way around).

---

**My question is**: Is there a way to make 1D convolutions work in this situation in `keras`?

---

**Note 1:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345934/1d-convolution-for-vector) SO question has the same problem, though without elaborating and the accepted answer does not solve the problem.
**Note 2:** I suppose I can convert each datapoint of my dataset to a 2D tensor of two rows where the second would be just 0's and use `Conv2D`'s, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all Ccnv layers in Keras there is one dimension defined for the number of channels. For example you can have an image which has 2 Dimensions but Conv2D needs 3 dimension (without batch). The reason is simply because the image can have one channel (gray scale) or 3 for example (colored). the same is true for a 1D signal which can be any signal with any number of channels. you can simply add one dimension to you data. if you have an numpy array:
`data = data[:, np.newaxis, :]` and setting channels_first `keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', name="conv_1, data_format="channels_first")`. you can do the same through adding extra dimension at the end and setting `data_format="channels_last"